# JS - Same function in each object in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I've got 2d array of object like chessboard.

You can get object by `data.field(x,y);` (object are stored inside 2d array of objects)

I want each of fields to have functions: `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` that will return neighbour field.

For example `data.field(3,3).top().left().bottom().name` would return name of field(4,3).

But: Have I to declare those function for each of objects? I mean, for example on 8x8 field that would be 64 instances of the same function:

```
data.field(0,0).top = function(){...}
data.field(0,1).top = function(){...}
...
```

Ofc I can easily declare them inside loop, but its pure waste of memory and I'm sure its not the way to do it. Is it possible to declare this functions only once to be available inside every object returned by field(x,y) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to declare this functions only once to be avaliable inside every object returned by field(x,y) function?

Absolutely:

```
function top() {
    // ...do your thing, using `this`
}

data.field(0,0).top = top;
```

When `top` is called as part of an expression retrieving it from the `field(0,0)` object, within the call to `top`, `this` will be the `field(0,0)` object. And similarly for `field(0,1)`, etc.

More (on my blog):

- [*Mythical Methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)

Now, that assumes that for whatever reason, you already have the `field(0,0)` and such objects (perhaps they're created by code you don't control). If you control the code, you can do this via the prototype chain instead:

```
function Field() {
}
Field.prototype.top = function() {
    // ...do your top thing, using `this`
};
```

...and when creating your fields:

```
yourField = new Field();
```

So it depends on what `data.fields(0,0)` is and where you get it.

Comment: @alex23: What's not OOP about attaching behaviors to objects?

Comment: Do I need to still do it for each of fields? data.field(0,0).top = top; data(0,1).top = top and so on?

Comment: @OPOPO: You do with the above, let me post an alternative. But note that although you're doing the assignment, you're not *duplicating* the function, you're just reusing it.

Comment: @alex23 you can do OOP without Classes, even without prototypes because JavaScript is _that_ awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conserve memory you should look at prototypes. They're like Classes in Object Oriented languages, so there is an opportunity for memory optimization.

```
var Field = function() {}; // this is your constructor
Field.prototype.top = function () { /* .. */
    return this; // return the field so you can do chaining: field.top().left();
};
Field.prototype.left = function () { /* .. */
    return this;
};
/* .. */
var field = new Field();
data.set(0, 0, field);
data.field(0, 0).top().left();
```